# How to tell if an estimator is unbiased? How to find expected value of an estimator?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

You come up with a great idea of an estimator for $\beta_1$ in the SLR model which satisfies SLR.1 to SLR.4:$$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+u_i$$ Given a sample $\left\{(x_i,y_i),i=1,2,3,\dots,n\right\}$, you connect the first sample observation to the second sample observation and compute the slope of the line: $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. Then you connect the first sample observation to the third sample observation and compute the slope of the line: $\frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_1}$. Repeat the same procedure to the rest of the observations in the sample and you estimate $\beta_1$ as the average of all $n-1$ slopes. In terms of a formula, your estimator is: $\tilde\beta_1=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=2}^n\left(\frac{y_i-y_1}{x_i-x_1}\right)$.

1. Is $\tilde\beta_1$ a linear estimator? i.e. can you express $\tilde\beta_1$ in the format of $\sum_{i=1}^nw_iy_i$ where all $w_i$ are functions of $x$ only. Clearly write down the $w_i$ in your answer.
2. Is $\tilde\beta_1$ an unbiased estimator conditional on a set of sample values of the independent variable $X=\left\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\right\}$? i.e. Is $E(\tilde\beta_1|X)=\beta_1$?

I am stuck with part 2. specifically. I am not sure how to find the expected value of $\tilde\beta_1$. I thought it might be just using the given $\tilde\beta_1$ formula and the sample of observations. I need some pointers on what I should think about while answering this question.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1):

First note that by definition, $y_i - y_1 = \beta_1(x_i-x_1) + u_i - u_1$, hence
$$\frac{y_i-y_1}{x_i-x_1} = \beta_1 + \frac{u_i-u_1}{x_i-x_1} $$
By applying the ["pull-out property"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018953/proving-the-pull-out-property-of-conditional-expectation) of conditional expectation, we have
$$\mathbb E\left[\frac{u_i-u_1}{x_i-x_1}\Big|\ X\right] =\frac{1}{x_i-x_1}\mathbb E\big[u_i-u_1\mid X\big] = 0 $$
Where the last inequality follows from assuming that the $u_i$ have zero mean given $X$.

We can finally put it all together by applying the linearity of expectation :
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb E\left[\tilde\beta_1
\big|\ X\right] &:= \mathbb E\left[\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=2}^n\left(\frac{y_i-y_1}{x_i-x_1}\right)
\Big|\ X\right]\\
&= \frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=2}^n\mathbb E\left[\left(\beta_1 + \frac{u_i-u_1}{x_i-x_1}
\right)
\Big|\ X\right]\\
&= \frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=2}^n \beta_1 = \beta_1
\end{align*} $$

And we conclude that $\tilde\beta_1$ is indeed a consistent estimator of $\beta_1$.

Comment: thanks so much. I've not heard of the "pull-out" property before, could you please explain it a bit further - why do we take out (x_i - x1)?

Comment: And also why b0 was taken out of the calculations - is it because it is constant?

Comment: Generally speaking, the pull out property tells you that if $Y$ and $Z$ are two random variables, $\mathcal F$ a $\sigma$-algebra and $Y$ is $\mathcal F$ measurable then
$$\mathbb E[YZ\mid\mathcal F] = Y\mathbb E[Z\mid \mathcal F] $$
The idea being that if $Y$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable then, given $\mathcal F$, $Y$ is "constant" and can thus be taken out of the expectation. Here I applied it with $Y :=\frac{1}{x_i-x_1}$, $Z:=u_i-u_1$ and $\mathcal F := \sigma (X) \equiv \sigma(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$

Comment: Nothing special about $\beta_0$, it's simply that we have $y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + u_1$ and $y_i :=\beta_0 +\beta_1 x_i + u_i$ hence when we take the difference $y_i - y_1$ the $\beta_0$ cancel each other

Comment: thanks again. I've also not heard of F-measurable, could you please explain that too?

Comment: You can read the formal definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Formal_definition), but roughly speaking a r.v. $Y$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable if all of its realizations can be described by events of $\mathcal F$. So if $\mathcal F$ is "known" (i.e. if we condition on $\mathcal F$), then $Y$ is also "known", which is why I said it's "like a constant" and can be taken out of the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[\cdot\mid\mathcal F] $. If you're looking for a more precise/detailed explanation I suggest you search this site and/or ask a separate question.